# I CANNOT IMPORT STATIC RESOURCES

Tags: jquery, html, spring, datatables

This is driving me crazy, I know there are tons of tutorials on this and trust me I have been through them all.  This is taking me far to long for something this simple. I am using Spring MVVC, I will post relevant code below

My main config class

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/crutch_resources/");
}
```

and a snippet from my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:urlvalue="crutch_resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:url value="crutch_resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:url value="crutch_resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js"/>"></script>
```

I am trying to get Datatables and jEditable plug ins to work - if I import datatables from a CDN it works so it has to be some error in my imports.

I am using maven so I have a standard web app structure.  Under src/main/ I have resources folder which has all my files (css/js).

The error I am getting is no mapping found and no handler for method

```
06:02:45.983 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /crutch_resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js
06:02:45.985 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/crutch_resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js]
06:02:45.985 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/crutchclothing/crutch_resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

thank you very much!

Comment: I'd suggest updating the subject title of your question to be more descriptive of the problem and not make it all caps.

Answer (score 0):

You mapped `/resources/crutch_resources/` to `/resources/**`. Now, when you want to call a resource that resides in the `crutch_resources` folder, you should use `/resources/` directly and Spring will map it to `/resources/crutch_resources/`.

Use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"src="<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js"/>"></script>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the comment, I changed the code how you specified and the jquery plugins still do not work. Thank you

Comment: 'code'    [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@7faec942] and 1 interceptor
14:19:24.344 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/crutchclothing/resources/js/jquery.jeditable.js] is: -1
14:19:24.344 DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [js/jquery.jeditable.js] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/crutch_resources/]
14:19:24.344 DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404'code'

Comment: What's the folder structure inside `crutch_resources`?

Comment: Inside crutch_resources I have 3 folders - js, css, images.  Inside those folders are sinlge files, .js, .css, etc.  Thank you